# Running a Rails app locally - creating local version of database schema with Rake failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake

I have a rails app that I'm trying to run on my local machine that was developed else where,
after battling a myriad of dependency issues, it seems like the last piece is the database not being locally installed, causing errors such as

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "lessons" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

Whenever I try to do rake db:setup I get

```
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
```

The database is a local Postgres db, I have made sure to create the user specified in database.yml, and Postgres is running.

Any ideas how I can get this app to run?

Comment: Could you please add your database.yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PG permissions error was a separate problem, however the relations not found issue was fixed by simply creating the missing supporting table manually, and the rest of the db setup job completed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is still not setup locally,:

1. Drop the database you created for your rails application.
2. Create a new Database with administrative privileges (as mentioned
   by @arunachalam. Also flush privileges)
3. Double check your database.yml credentials.
4. run: rake db:migrate directly.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the user in your database.yml file doesn't have superuser privileges in PostgreSQL which would allow creation of databases. The solution is to create the database manually, with a user that has those rights.

- Create the database:

  - Run `psql` in terminal, to access your local PostgreSQL databases.
  - `\du` lists existing roles and privileges. Make sure you are logged in as a role with superuser privileges. The role name used by `database.yml` should ideally not have superuser privileges, because of potential harmful authorities (which could harm other projects using PostgreSQL on your machine).
  - `\list` will list all PostgreSQL databases on your machine.
  - `CREATE DATABASE <database> OWNER <username>;` will create the database. Replace the info inside the <> tags with info from your `database.yml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Make your user superuser:

```
alter role your_role_name with superuser;
```

Now create database with same user.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is the user may not be an administrator, With the user name  you have trying using [ALTER ROLE -](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-alterrole.html) in PostgreSQL .then you should be able to use rake db:setup or db:create .

you can also add new users with administrator role  to .yml file

Comment: what did you mean by "you can also add new users with administrator role to .yml file"?

Comment: Anyone know what the best practices are in this situation? Is it better to alter the role of your underprivileged user and create the DB with that user, or to use the superuser (which is usually the username "postgres" I believe).

Comment: @Dennis I presume the latter, since that won't permanently grant potentially harmful authorities to the normal db user.

Comment: contd... A superuser could harm other projects using PostgreSQL on your machine. See my answer for how I solved it.